# Modeling GLMM with nested and repeated measures

Tags: repeated-measures, glmm, nested-data

I'm new to modeling GLMMs and I'm having trouble to create a model for analyze my data. I'm doing a leaf damage analysis (response variable) depending on the group (with ants and without ants) and leaf age (three analyzes over the time). I analyzed three leaves per plant, which is a nested factor.
I have:

1. herbi - herbivory rate (response)
2. group - two levels (with ants and without ants)
3. age - three levels (young, intermediate and adult - same leaf, that is, over time)
4. plant - individuals
5. leaf - three leaf per plant (nested in plant)

So, I fit the following model:

```
m1<-lmer(herbi~group*age + (1|plant/leaf))
```

Any advice?